# Is there any alternative for showing overlay on another application always other than TimerTask?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am building an application which shows overlay over another application like a app locker do. but its not like it. I want to show a dialog on an application which exists on database every time i open the application. I have made a service which continuously checks for which application is in foreground using a timer task set at delay and period of 1sec.

The problem is that it shows the dialog only one time on every application due to one statement inside the timer task run function. How can i make it work so that it always shows dialog on the application. Any alternative or optimizations?

```
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.Service
import android.app.usage.UsageStats
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import app.privvio.android.policysplash.PolicyDialog
import app.privvio.android.preference.GetFirebaseAllApps
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class AppCheckServices : Service() {
private var context: Context? = null
var imageView: ImageView? = null
private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null
private var dialog: Dialog? = null
var dbPackageName: ArrayList<String> = GetFirebaseAllApps().getAppsUploaded()


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    context = applicationContext

    /** Timer started for long time **/
    timer = Timer("AppCheckServices")
    timer!!.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateTask, 1000L, 1000L)


    /** Window Manager posts a Blank Image
     * view with transparent background which blocks the view
     * and the policy dialog is shown over it
     * **/
    windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    imageView = ImageView(this)
    imageView!!.visibility = View.GONE

    val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
    }
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT)
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.CENTER
    params.x = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2
    params.y = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2
    windowManager!!.addView(imageView, params)
}


private val updateTask: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    override fun run() {
        currentApp = ForegroundApps
        if (dbPackageName.contains(ForegroundApps)) {
            Log.d("DBAppFRGRND", "true : The application is in foreground.")
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView!!.post {
                    if (currentApp != previousApp) {
                        showPolicyDialog()
                        previousApp = currentApp
                    } else {
                        Log.d("AppCheckService", "currentApp matches previous App")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("DBAppFRGRND", "false : The application is not uploaded to the server. ")
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView!!.post {
                    hidePolicyDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/** This section tells whether an application is in foreground or background */
val ForegroundApps: String?
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    get() {
        var mpackageName: String? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            val usm = this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val appList: List<UsageStats>? = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, 0, time)
            if (appList != null && appList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val sortedMap = TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>()
                for (usageStats in appList) {
                    sortedMap[usageStats.lastTimeUsed] = usageStats
                }
                mpackageName = sortedMap.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.lastEntry()?.value?.packageName
                Log.d(TAG, "isEmpty No : $mpackageName")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "isEmpty Yes")
                mpackageName = ""
            }
        } else {
            val am = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION") //The deprecated method is used for devices running an API lower than LOLLIPOP
            mpackageName = am.getRunningTasks(5)[0].topActivity?.packageName
            Log.d(TAG, "isEmpty No : $mpackageName")
        }
        return mpackageName
    }

fun showPolicyDialog() {
    if (context == null) context = applicationContext
    PolicyDialog(context!!).showDialog(context!!)
}

fun hidePolicyDialog() {
    previousApp = ""
    try {
        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog!!.isShowing) {
                dialog!!.dismiss()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    /** We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
     * stopped, so return sticky.
     */
    return START_STICKY
}


 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
  //        timer!!.cancel()
  //        timer = null
    if (imageView != null) {
        windowManager!!.removeView(imageView)
    }
    try {
        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog!!.isShowing) {
                dialog!!.dismiss()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}


companion object {
    const val TAG = "AppCheckServices"
    var currentApp: String? = ""
    var previousApp: String? = ""
    var timer: Timer? = null
}
```

}